# Android's Action Bar visiblity

Tags: usability, android

I need advice regarding Android's action bar usage. Do you think an action bar should always:

a) remain visible on all screens of an application (except when the user choose to view for example a video in full screen)

or

b) invisible on certain screens and visible only on suitable screen for example, a list with description, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about Action Bar, I presume you're designing for Ice Cream Sandwich. In that case, let's take a look at what [Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) have to say about it:

> The action bar is arguably the most important structural element of an Android app. It's a dedicated piece of real estate at the top of each screen that is generally persistent throughout the app.

This means that unless there's a [contextual need](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual) or something needs to be viewed in full screen mode (like a video), the Action Bar should be visible. By function, you can think of it as iOS's [Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) joined with the [Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52) because Action Bar merges navigation and actions into one control element.